# Windows 10 boot failure

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootrepair

Had bsod. Mini dump file indicated memory corruption. Subsequent attempts at rebooting resulted in Windows attempting automatic repair unsuccessfully.

Memtest x86 identified one of two 8 GB stick of memory was bad. This was removed and the remaining 8 GB  tested good.

The boot behavior of the computer did not change. Srttrail.txt showed

```
root cause found:

boot critical file D:\boot\resources\custom\bootres.dll is corrupt.
```

> And it was unable to repair the file.

I've tried restore points which were unsuccessful. I tried doing a repair reinstall with an ISO image of Windows 10. Apparently, since the image could not confirm that I had a working version of Windows 10, it would not allow that process to occur.

I ran chkdsk /f and sfc scannow.

I examined the folder reference in the error message in what I think is the boot volume by entering the command prompt after the failed recovery. That file does not exist in the referenced folder.

It does exist in C:\boot\resources\ (one folder up).

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to repair the boot sector using the `bcdboot` command.  Of interest to me, and pertinent in the end result, was that `bootrec /ScanOS` showed `0` installations compatible with windows.  So that tool couldn't be used to rebuild the boot sector.  And `bcdboot` resulted in a non-bootable computer.

So I bit the bullet and resolved to do a clean install of Windows 10 from a downloaded ISO burned to a DVD.

As I wrote above, I was not able to choose the option to retain my files. Perhaps that was related to `bootrec` not detecting an windows compatible install?

And much to my surprise, all of my personal files were found in the `windows.old` file.  (I did have everything backed up, but it was much more convenient to have the files on my HD instead of having to recover from the backup medium.

In summary, I was not able to recover my windows installation, but I am up and running again, and should be getting replacement memory next week (Crucial has a lifetime warranty on their memory, so it won't cost me anything).